# Upload SSH public key to bitbucket cloud using curl/REST and token

Tags: rest, curl, bitbucket

I have a bitbucket cloud account. Under: https://id.atlassian.com/manage/api-tokens I have generated an API Token which I am trying to use in a REST call to upload 
a public SSH key to my account. Based on:

https://docs.atlassian.com/bitbucket-server/rest/5.6.2/bitbucket-ssh-rest.html?utm_source=%2Fstatic%2Frest%2Fbitbucket-server%2F5.6.2%2Fbitbucket-ssh-rest.html&utm_medium=301#idm45427244388592

https://community.atlassian.com/t5/Answers-Developer-Questions/Bitbucket-REST-API-POST-using-token-instead-of-basic-auth/qaq-p/474823

I have tried:

```
curl -X POST -d '{"text":"ssh-rsa AAAAB3... me@127.0.0.1"}' -H "Authorization: Bearer ADasdaEeasAsd..." https://bitbucket.org/[my-account]]/rest/ssh/latest/keys
```

But when I run that I get:

```
{"type": "error", "error": {"message": "Access token expired. Use your refresh token to obtain a new access token."}}
```

I have tried to re-create the token and re-run the above command again - with the new token - but I get the same error.

Any suggestions?

Based on below answer and link I have now tried:

```
curl -X POST \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-H "Authorization: Bearer wxdrtblabla..." \
-d '{"key": "ssh-ed25519 AAAAC3NzaC1lZDI1NTE5AAAAIKqP3Cr632C2dNhhgKVcon4ldUSAeKiku2yP9O9/bDtY myuser@bitbucket.org/myuser"}' \
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/users/myuser/ssh-keys
```

But I get the exact same error:

```
{"type": "error", "error": {"message": "Access token expired. Use your refresh token to obtain a new access token."}}
```

So still no luck. Also if I access:

https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/users/[myuser]/ssh-keys

directly in a browser I get:

```
type    "error"
error   
message "This API is only accessible with the following authentication types: session, password, apppassword"
```

**EDIT/ANSWERED:** Based on the updated answer below I have no tried to create an **app password** and grant it **account: read/write** in bitbucket and it works. I  run it with:

```
curl -v -u myuser:my-generated-app-password -X POST  \
-H "Content-Type: application/json" \
-d '{"key": "ssh-rsa AAA....ro"}' \
https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/users/myuser/ssh-keys
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You're looking at Bitbucket Server documentation but using Bitbucket Cloud. (The giveaways: the "bitbucket-server" part of the doc path, and the "bitbucket.org" in the path where you're pushing your key.)

Check out https://developer.atlassian.com/bitbucket/api/2/reference/resource/users/%7Busername%7D/ssh-keys#post instead - that's the Bitbucket Cloud documentation to do what you're trying to do. Your URL will be more like `https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/users/[your-account]/ssh-keys`.

EDIT: The error you received indicates the problem: you either need to make that call from within an existing session (i.e. from the GUI), use your password, or use an [app password](https://confluence.atlassian.com/bitbucket/app-passwords-828781300.html). I'd recommend the app password, since it's scoped, meant to be disposable, and won't let you log onto the GUI. Your curl call then becomes something like `curl -u myuser:myapppassword -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d '{"key": "key content goes here"}' https://api.bitbucket.org/2.0/users/myuser/ssh-keys`.